# Check if dictionary is empty

Tags: c++-cli

I have a c++-cli function with input argument a dictionary of strings

```
Locate(Dictionary<String^, String^>^ Dic)
```

Sometimes the Dic that is being passed is empty. No entries at all in the first string or second string. How can I check if the dictionary Dic is completely empty? I know that TryGetValue works only if the first String exists.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the [Count](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f.aspx) property:

```
bool isEmpty = Dic->Count == 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never used CLI, but a quick MSDN search for the Dictionary container shows it has a [`Count` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhcy256f.aspx) which indicates *"The number of key/value pairs contained in the Dictionary"*.  Presumably you can test this value for zero.

Answer (score 1):

the .net object [Dictionnary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) has a property named Count.

I guess the c++/cli can call the value of that property: something like dict->Count, or dict->Count().

And then you test the returned value.